Why does this integration not work
Its shown in the image attached, im having alot of trouble with it trying to understand what mechanism makes it wrong. Because i keep doing this accross questions for QCAA specialist maths. I would really appreciate help as its messing with me leading upto to my finals.
Fundamentally why does this particular teachnique not work as it seems to have a wrong answer according to all graphing software and the states marking scheme. The question is irrelevant just this particular integration im doing is acting wierd. And in terms of highschool calculus it seems valid as my teachers couldn't tell me what was happening after an hour of them working on it.
Sorry i didnt know how to work the formatting thhannks for the help


Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Here is how to "work the formatting"

How did you go from the second line the to the third line?

Cf. this question

As u = du/dx as they both equal e^x

@DevTheHall Sorry, I mean third line to the answer

$$\int\frac{u'\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\ne\int\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\sin^{-1}u+C$$

Math guy does the chain rule not apply to inverse trig derivatives?

@DevTheHall It does, the problem is that the integral would have to be in $dx$ instead of $du$ since you differentiated with respect to $x$

Ohh i get it now its because you have to apply it all in terms of du so derivative of u in terms of u on top even when applying chhain rule logic thanks guys

Noting that
$$
I=\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2 x}}} e^x d x=\int \frac{e^{2 x} d x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2 x}}}
$$
Put $u=1-e^{2x}$, then $du=-2e^{2x}dx$ and $e^{2x}dx=-\frac{du}{2} $.  Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{d u}{2 \sqrt{u}} \\
& =\sqrt{u}+c \\
& =\sqrt{1-e^{2 x}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Why not $u=\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}$ instead ? Cheers :-)

Yup, both can work. I think this substitution is simpler to OP.
